# Firebase Crash Reporting: Shared preference in Application must be multi-process safe

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, firebase-crash-reporting

As per stated in https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues,

> Crash Reporting creates a separate background process to upload crash info. If your app extends the Android Application class, you must ensure it is multi-process safe

The item we need to watch out are

> a database, the file system, shared preferences, etc

I read shared preferences from my Application. How do I ensure it is multi-process safe?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change your approach. Unfortunately, as documented in the Android API, [SharedPreferences are not safe to use from multiple processes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Note: This class does not support use across multiple processes.

Firebase Crash Reporting currently adds a second process to your app; `Application.onCreate()` is called once for each process, so the shared preferences would be accessed from multiple processes, which is likely to cause problems.

Your alternatives are to move the `SharedPreferences` logic out of the Application class, or to wait with integrating Crash Reporting until Firebase has changed their design to not use a second process - they are actively working on it and will have it changed before they leave Beta.

If you decide to move the `SharedPreferences` logic, one approach can be to move it into a `ContentProvider`, as those are run in just a single process, before `Application.onCreate()`. I shared an example of this design in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39055494/436417).