# "Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists."

Tags: android, service, firebase

So I was trying to use Firebase in an Android service **which is in a seperate process** and this error came up while doing:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()....
or
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()....
```

I wrote this check snippet to overcome the problem:

```
boolean hasBeenInitialized=false;
List<FirebaseApp> firebaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps(this);
for(FirebaseApp app : firebaseApps){
    if(app.getName().equals("[DEFAULT]")){
        hasBeenInitialized=true;
    }
}

if(!hasBeenInitialized) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this));
}

// Only then getInstance() will work
```

And **IT WORKS** pretty good **BUT** I'm not sure this is the right way to do it (it's the hardcoded `[DEFAULT]` that bothers me...).

Does anyone knows a proper way to do this ?

Comment: Do you want to access your fire base database with out user login from app, is this the requirement?

Comment: No, it's not about the authentication or the database themselves, it's about the error that Firebase throws when I try to use any of its functionality in an Android service. I would like to know if there is a "right way" to do it

Comment: I am not sure, but i remember resolving similar issue moving code inside Application.oncreate to MainActivity.oncreate. My app was crashing in my case.

Comment: do you have disk persistence option enabled? can you post your Application class?

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is nothing in my Application class about Firebase. Should I have something ? (I didn't enable anything...)

Comment: In your manifest, do you declare the service to be in a separate process?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm adding this information in the post

Comment: With your service in a separate process, the problem would normally be that Firebase App is not initialized for that process, rather than it being already initialized.  Are you sure there is no code in your Application class that is causing Firebase to init?  An instance of the Application class runs in each process of your app.

Comment: Related issue (although for Analytics): http://stackoverflow.com/a/39055494/4815718

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare to `FirebaseApp.DEFAULT_APP_NAME` instead. See the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.html#DEFAULT_APP_NAME).